# field of decomposition of $x^3+ax+b$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$

Tags: galois-theory

I need to answer the following question:

Suppose $f(x)=x^3+ax+b$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. Why is his field of decomposition $\mathbb{F}_{p^{3n}}?$

Also, how do we know $f(x)$ has a Galois Group $Gal(\mathbb{F}_{p^{3n}}/\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}})$? Since $\mathbb{F}_{p^{3n}}$ is its field of decomposition, we only need  $f(x)$ to be separable. But

$f'(x)=3x^2-a=3x^2 \in \mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$
So $\gcd(f'(x),f(x))=1, $ because $b \neq 0$ because otherwise it becomes reducible. Therefore $f(x)$ is separable. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)=x^3+ax+b$ is clearly separable if $p\neq 3$. If $p=3$ then $f(x)$ is separable unless $a=0$. But if $a=0$ then $f(x)=(x+c)^3$, where $c$ is an element of $\mathbb{F}_{3^n}$ such that $c^3=b$. So since $f$ is irreducible, $a$ must be non-zero.

Hence if $E=\mathbb{F}_{p^n}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $[E:\mathbb{F}_{p^n}]=3$, so $E=\mathbb{F}_{p^{3n}}$ since there is a unique finite field of each prime power cardinality. As finite extensions of finite fields are Galois extensions, this means that $E$ is Galois over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$, so $E$ is the splitting field of $f$.

Comment: can you give me more details on the separability of f(x)? I do not see it.

Comment: Since f is irreducible, it cannot have a common factor with its derivative unless f'=0.